# Android (ReactNative) - Google Sign In (without firebase) not working after publishing to Playstore

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, google-signin

I am getting an error **"A non-recoverable sign in failure occurred"** and sometimes **"DEVELOPER_ERROR"**.

Google Sign In behaviour isn't consistent, sometimes it works and sometimes it stops.

I've found solutions, which said google introduced App Signing Key, we have to put that into the firebase console but I am not using firebase in my case, how do I use the App Signing Key and where do I put it?